# How can I call the retrieved JSON object from one method to another without storing it as a string?

Tags: java, json, api

I have retrieved a JSON object from my response on one method in my Java class. Now I want to use the same object in my another method in the same class. How do I do it?

Comment: Could you give an example of your code and why it doesn't work? Getting an object from one method and passing it as a parameter to another method is pretty much Java 101? Is your question specifically about json or are you relatively new to Java?

Comment: If this really is about JSON, it would help if you also mentioned the json library you're working with.

Comment: Store it as a JsonObject in a data member. Class data members are shared between its methods.

Comment: @Matt I am new to Java too.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I am using Unirest

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Can you please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by "call the [...] json object"? In Java, a json object is just a data structure, with methods that work on that (JSON API), but you cannot call specialized business logic on it. Do you mean to pass the retrieved json object to another method? Then just add it to the parameter list  --- basic Java 101, like @Matt says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have plenty of ways to achieve what you want:

First you can make a field in your class and instantiate it when you retrieve your object.

Then you can use it in your class wherever you want. You can even make it `public` and use it in other classes too.

For example:

```
public class JsonReader{
     public JsonObject object; //field in your class (still not instantiated)
     public JsonReader(){
         object = readMyJson(); //declare a readMyJson method to retrieve your object
         ...
     }
     //other methods
     public someFunction(){
         //here you have access to your object.
     }
}
```

Or you can pass local variables to each method as @Matt answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are new to Java, the basic format for passing a parameter around is to assign it with `=`:

```
public void callerMethod() {
    JsonObject myResponse = getResponse();   // call the method and put the response in the variable
    doSomething(myResponse);                 // pass the variable to a method
}

private void doSomething(JsonObject myResponse) {    // this method gets the variable from the call above
    // do whatever you want with myResponse here
}
```

Hope that helps?